# Google Sheet Function with IF statement to add 1/0 column

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I want to query a number of rows from one sheet into another sheet, and to the right of this row add a column based on one of the queried columns. Meaning that if column C is "Il", I want to add a column to show 0, otherwise 1 (the samples below will make it clearer.

I have tried doing this with `Query` and `Arrayformula`, without `query`, with `Filter` and `importrange`. An example of what I tried:

```
=query(Data!A1:AG,"Select D, E, J, E-J, Q, AG " & IF(AG="Il",0, 1),1)
```

Raw data sample:

```
Captured Amount Fee     Country
 TRUE    336    10.04   NZ
 TRUE    37     1.37    GB
 TRUE    150    4.65    US
 TRUE    45     1.61    US
 TRUE    20     0.88    IL
```

What I would want as a result:

```
Amount  Fee     Country  Sort
 336    10.04   NZ       1
 37     1.37    GB       1
 150    4.65    US       1
 45     1.61    US       1
 20     0.88    IL       0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Data!A1:Q, {"Sort"; IF(Data!AG2:AG="IL", 0, 1)}}, 
 "select Col4,Col5,Col9,Col5-Col9,Col17,Col18 label Col5-Col9''", 1))
```